# C++ Can someone explain string( )

Tags: c++

```
vector< string > tokenize( string in, string kar ) { 

  string::iterator cp = in.begin(); 
  vector< string > oot; 

  while( cp != in.end() ) { 

    while( cp != in.end() && count( kar.begin(), kar.end(), *cp ) ) 
      cp++; 
    if( cp != in.end() ) 
      oot.push_back( string( cp, find_first_of( cp, in.end(), kar.begin(), kar.end() ) ) ); 
    cp = find_first_of( cp, in.end(), kar.begin(), kar.end() ); 

  }; 

  return oot; 
};
```

Can someone explain this line:

```
string( cp, find_first_of( cp, in.end(), kar.begin(), kar.end() )
```

What is the use of this line?
I wonder can we replace this line with just the single word *cp instead of that long line.

Comment: Here is a link to the reference.  Go read it. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the use of this line?

`find_first_of` finds the first occurrence of any character in `kar`, from `cp` to the end of the string (giving the end of the string if none are found). `kar` contains the characters used to delimit tokens, so this finds the end of the token that starts with `cp`.

Then make a string containing the characters from `cp` up to, but not including, the delimiter that was found. This string is a single token, so push it onto the sequence of tokens we're going to return.

> I wonder can we replace this line with just the single word `*cp`

No, `*cp` is a single character, not a single word. To get the whole token, you need to find the end of the token, which is what this code does.

You could simplify the code by only searching for the end of the token once:

```
if (cp != in.end()) {
    string::iterator token_end = find_first_of( cp, in.end(), kar.begin(), kar.end() );
    oot.push_back(string(cp, token_end));
    cp = token_end;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This constructs a string based on two iterators, `cp` starting iterator, and the result of `first_first_of()`, which looks like it's looking for the first element in the range `kar.begin() -> kar.end()` in the range `cp` to end of the string `in`.

So, no you cannot do what you just said (any way `*cp` is a character.)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
string( cp, find_first_of( cp, in.end(), kar.begin(), kar.end() )
```

Creates an *unnamed* (ie, anonymous) instance of a `std::`string`, using the 4 parameters provided.

Looking at this in a wider context:

```
oot.push_back( string( cp, find_first_of( cp, in.end(), kar.begin(), kar.end() ) ) );
```

Shows that the constructed unnamed string is then passed to `push_back`.  After this code completes, the unnamed `string` falls out of scope and is destroyed -- it is a temporary.